# Vim syntastic scss error, doesn't read the imported files

Tags: css, vim, configuration, syntastic

How to make vim syntastic to read the imported files? 
Currently my scss directory files like this:

```
scss/
----custom.scss
----style.scss
----variable.scss
```

I import all the scss file into `style.scss`, so the style.scss contains:

```
@import 'variable';
@import 'custom';
```

That's fine, then in my `variable.scss`, e.g I make a variable of color `$primary-color: #3298df;`. Then in my `custom.scss` contains:

```
a, p {
    color: $primary-color;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The vim syntastic will notify me an error saying that `Undefined variable: $primary-color`, but if I build the scss file and run in the browser, it works fine.

Any clue for the vim syntastic configuration ?

Comment: It's a "cart before the horse" situation - you just need to reorder your `import` lines so the variables are called first, before they're used.

Comment: @JonUleis The vim syntastic still notifies me an error. Pardon me before, actually in my `style.scss` I have ordered files that contain variables or any mixin in the top first before `import` another scss files.